# Expo react-native update icon on build app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas

So I want to update the icon of my mobile app. But it won't change. I've already published an update that went successful, the in app changes has been changed. The only thing that has not been changed is the icon.

How can I update it?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/introduction/), expo updates only changes the `non-native parts` of the app (eg: JS, styling and images those are inside pages of your app).

App icon is a native part of the app so you'll need to release a new `.ipa` or `.aab` and publish them to revision inside stores so your app will update and change the icon (or any other native part)